# Ubuntu One for MAC 10.6 or higher says on 10.6.8 "Ubuntu one cannot run on this type of MAC"

Tags: ubuntu-one, mac, software-installation

I downloaded the Beta and installed Ubuntu One. There is a "No Entry" sign on the UO logo, try to run but gives the above error message. This is an intel mac book pro with a core duo and MAC OS V10.6.8

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately Ubuntu One for Mac OS does not currently run on 32-bit processors like the Core Duo. This is not a fundamental limitation, but just a lack of resources. See [this launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/1066397) if you would like to vote to give this issue higher priority.